# How do I redirect Console Output to PowerShell Output within a module?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

If I'm writing a binary PowerShell module and I happen to use a .NET library that writes to STDOUT (`Console.Out`) -- is there a recommended approach to *reroute* the console output to PowerShell's Output stream?

I can intercept the `Console.Out` by setting my own `TextWriter` via `Console.SetOut(...)` and then do something with it (i.e. I can buffer the output with a `StringWriter` and write it all out at some future point, or I can write a custom `TextWriter` that sends all `Write` commands to PowerShell's `WriteObject`).

My question is really, is there some standard or recommended practice for doing this or some built-in tools in the PowerShell library already?

Comment: I don't think so. What you describe (wrap WriteObject() in a TextWriter and set it as Console.Out) is exactly what I would have suggested

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be the guidance from PS team as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question of the PS team via GitHub and the general response was that the TextWriter-to-WriteObject approach was a reasonable approach:  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4849

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output to the pipeline use `WriteObject()`. `WriteInformation()`, `WriteDebug()`, `WriteWarning()` gets a message (string) to the host.

Comment: Yes, that's fine for content that I control, but the point of the question was how to redirect someone else's output that goes to the STDIO output?  In any even the solution was confirmed by the PS team -- you simply have to do the redirection yourself.